# Pinch Zoom Activation on Jquery Mobile based Rhodes app

Tags: jquery-mobile, zooming, rhomobile, pinch

I am trying to activate Pinch-Zoom in my app made on Jquery Mobile (Rhomobile Framework)

I have put

```
<% if is_bb6 %>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
    <% else %>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=3.0;user-scalable=1;"/>
    <% end %>
```

What to do? Any ideas?

I use jquery mobile RC1

But I can upgrade....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track the following ticket on their public PivotalTracker site.  It looks like development has commenced and should be available soon.

https://www.pivotaltracker.com/story/show/16384375